# How to note down the multiple null columns from the multiple table with a single query, procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have various tables having various column more than hundred in each or that can increase. Also, in my tables there are certain columns having null value with some data as well as completely null column

I just need the columns which have completely null values or in better understanding the row count of that table should be equal to the null count of the rows of column present in that table

```
DECLARE
    TYPE refc IS ref CURSOR;
    col_cv   REFC;
    l_query  VARCHAR(3999);
    v_rownum NUMBER;
    v_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    l_query := 'select rownum from &table_name ';

    FOR col IN (SELECT table_name,
                       column_name
                FROM   user_tab_columns
                WHERE  table_name = ' ') LOOP
        l_query := l_query
                   ||'DECODE('
                   ||col.column_name
                   ||',NULL,1,0)+';
    END LOOP;

    l_query := l_query
               ||'+0 as no_of_null_values from ... ';

    dbms_output.Put_line(l_query);

    OPEN col_cv FOR l_query;

    LOOP
        FETCH col_cv INTO v_rownum, v_count;

        EXIT WHEN col_cv%NOTFOUND;

        dbms_output.Put_line(v_rownum
                             || ' '
                             || v_count);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE col_cv;
END;
```

Comment: declare
TYPE refc IS REF CURSOR; 
  col_cv refc; 
  l_query varchar(3999);
  v_rownum number;
  v_count number;
begin
l_query := 'select rownum from &table_name ';
for col in (select table_name, column_name 
from user_tab_columns where table_name='.... ')
loop
l_query := l_query ||'DECODE('||col.column_name||',NULL,1,0)+';  
end loop;
l_query := l_query||'+0 as no_of_null_values from ... ';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);
OPEN col_cv FOR l_query;
LOOP
FETCH col_cv into v_rownum, v_count;
EXIT WHEN col_cv%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rownum || ' ' || v_count);
END LOOP;
CLOSE col_cv;
end;

Comment: "*having null value with some data*" - how is that possible? It's either `null` or it has data.

Comment: i mean to say there are some columns with null value in 1st row and some data in 2nd row,  but i need only those column which has completely null value

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select sum(case when column_1 is null then 1) as column_1_null_count,
       sum(case when column_2 is null then 1) as column_2_null_count,
       ... the above for all columns ...
       count(*) as total_rows
from the_table
where column_1_null_count = total_rows
   or column_2_null_count = total_rows
```

Should be pretty easy to generate that dynamically based user_tab_columns.

Comment: I GOT THE ANSWER   {set serveroutput on;
declare
CURSOR COLNAME IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name='&table_name' ;
tot number;
stmt varchar2(500);
begin
FOR mrec IN COLNAME 
LOOP
--cname:= mrec.COLUMN_NAME;
--tot := 0;
stmt := 'select count(*)  from &table_name where ' || mrec.column_name  || ' is not null ' ;
 execute immediate stmt into tot;
if tot = 0 then 
dbms_output.put_line('COLUMN containing null IS ' || mrec.COLUMN_NAME);
end if;
end loop;
end;}

Answer (score 0):

To count values in a column use COUNT(column). If you get a count of 0 then there is no value in that column, i.e. the column is null in all records (or the table doesn't contain any record). Here is a function to find all columns not containing any value:

```
declare
  v_count integer;
begin
  for rec in (select table_name, column_name from user_tab_cols) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(' || rec.column_name || ') from ' || rec.table_name into v_count;
    if v_count = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.table_name || '.' || rec.column_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
set serveroutput on;
    declare
    CURSOR COLNAME IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name='&table_name' ;
    tot number;
    stmt varchar2(500);
    begin
    FOR mrec IN COLNAME 
    LOOP
    --cname:= mrec.COLUMN_NAME;
    --tot := 0;
    stmt := 'select count(*)  from &table_name where ' || mrec.column_name  || ' is not null ' ;
     execute immediate stmt into tot;
    if tot = 0 then 
    dbms_output.put_line('COLUMN containing null IS ' || mrec.COLUMN_NAME);
    end if;
    end loop;
    end;
```